# Moving existing WordPress site on trial Azure to another Azure account

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service, move, migrate

I currently have a WordPress site on a trial account on Azure.  The trial is running out in a week so I need to migrate it to another existing Azure account.  I was hoping to get some help on how to move the entire site.

I exported a WPRESS File + XML Doc under WordPress dashboard and created a backup storage account (on trial Azure).

Would it be just as simple as creating a new WP site on the non-trial account and importing the WPRESS File?  Any help or insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you use a plugin like [`All-in-One WP Migration`](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/#description) to migrate your WordPress site to a different location.

Installation instructions: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/#installation